# i'm working with postgreSQL with converting long/lat to point and also want to make line with that point

Tags: postgresql, postgis

i'm working with postgreSQL with converting long/lat to point and also want to make line with that point

```
select bs1.rental_shop_name,
    bs1.lon,
    bs1.lat,
    bs2.rental_shop_name,
    bs2.lon,
    bs2.lat,
    count(*),
    ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(bs1.lon, bs1.lat), ST_MakePoint(bs2.lon, bs2.lat))
from bikeuser as bu
join bikestation as bs1 on bs1.rental_shop_code = bu.rental_shop_code
join bikestation as bs2 on bs2.rental_shop_code = bu.return_shop_code
group by bs1.rental_shop_name,
    bs1.lon,
    bs1.lat,
    bs2.rental_shop_name,
    bs2.lon,
    bs2.lat,
    ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(bs1.lon, bs1.lat), ST_MakePoint(bs2.lon, bs2.lat))
order by count desc limit 40
```

but result is failed and msg is

> SQL state: 42883 the st_makepoint does not exist and also have to use explicit converter

also i tested with simple form like this.

```
SELECT ST_MakePoint(-71.1043443253471, 42.3150676015829);
```

BUT ITS SAME RESULTS...

Comment: ST_MakePoint is not a standard PostgreSQL function, it's part of PostGIS, did you install it?

Comment: http://postgis.net/install/

Answer (score 0):

Just ST_MakePoint is not enough with lat long. You have to set SRID of the geometry as well. If the data comes from WGS84(which usually is the case with lat long), you need to apply ST_SetSRID on the geometry.

```
   ST_MakeLine(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(bs1.lon, bs1.lat),4326), ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(bs2.lon, bs2.lat),4326))
```

You should take into account your own data SRID.